# Is there a widget or something I can go with IFTTT to block and unblock a contact?

Tags: app-widgets, sms-blocking, ifttt

I have a friend that says some pretty bad things about certain people pretty often and a lot of the time I am around those people while he's sending me those messages.

I just want a button/widget I can use to discreetly block his texts and calls quickly, like as the person is walking up to me and will arrive in less than 3 seconds.

Does that exist? Can I use IFTTT to do something like that?

Comment: Can't you just pocket your device when there is a person approaching you?

Comment: Also, it is no one's job to fascilitate bad actors, even if they are our friends. Why do you let yourself remain an enabler?

Comment: He's my son and she is my wife. He is also my best friend and I married his mother. She's nuts and questions everything.

Comment: Imagine the questions she would have if his contact incredulously disappeared from your phone in her presence all the time. Your best friend not in your phone? "What else are you hiding from me?!?"